# iText Receiving Default constructor cannot handle exception type IOException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

Tags: itext

Im stumped.Im trying to add an immage watermark in iText

I have received the above titled message when entering

**Image watermark_image = Image.getInstance("c:/images/MyImage.png");**

I have no idea how to define an explicit constructor in iText?

Im using the iTextg 5.5.9 jar file.

Any help is MOST appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Please provide a snippet of your actual code, it's not clear how defining an explicit constructor is tied into the IOException you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general java error, not iText related.

You have two options.

Catch the exception

```
Image watermark_image = null;
try {
    watermark_image = Image.getInstance("c:/images/MyImage.png");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or add a throws clause to your method definition:

```
public void getImageInstance() throws IOException {
    watermark_image = Image.getInstance("c:/images/MyImage.png");
}
```

Comment: The `getInstance()` method already throws an `IOException`. See the API docs: http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html#getInstance-java.lang.String-

Comment: Then Im not sure why Im getting the error? What do I do?

Comment: Got it ... When it's spelled out to me, I can pick it up pretty quick. (:-{()